# Convert all SVG text nodes into path nodes with Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm attempting to write a [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) function that will take existing text nodes within a [Raphael paper](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper) instance and convert them into paths.

The goal is to replicate the position, size and attribute of the text exactly as it appears on the page, but have it rendered using paths instead of text.  I cannot initially render the text using the Raphael [paper.print()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.print) function because the text is updated dynamically and requires "text" based attributes to do so.  Converting existing text nodes to paths will occur as the "final" step in the process (after the text modifications are complete).

I am doing this to eliminate the need for having fonts installed to view or handle the SVG later.

The challenges I face are:

1. Text nodes may include tspans with `x` and `dy` definitions.  The paths created must line it perfectly witch each of the childNode letters (tspans).
2. Retrieving the actual position data of text node, and each tspan.  This is where I'm having trouble and hopefully someone with more experience can assist me.  Since stroke widths and other attributes affect the positioning/bbox values, I'm not sure what's the most efficient method of obtaining the correct positioning data for the text.

**What I have tried so far:**

A simple breakdown of my code.

I wrote a custom attribute function, textFormat, that formats the text in a staggered formation.  This function parses the text node, splits it by each letter adding a new line `\n` character, and adjusts the positioning to look staggered.

The textToPaths function is a paper function that is supposed to loop through the paper nodes, and convert all found text nodes into path using the Raphael [paper.print()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.print) function.  This is the function I am having trouble with.

[View the Complete JSFiddle Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7RurJ/4/)

**The problem code**
I'm not sure how to obtain accurate and consistent `x` and `y` values to pass into the `paper.print()` function.  Right now, I am using `getBoundingClientRect()` but it's still off and skewed.  My assumption is the stroke widths are affecting the x and y calculations.

```
        //Loop through each tspan and print the path for each.
        var i,
            children = node.node.childNodes,
            len = children.length;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var tspan = children[i],
                tspanText = tspan.innerHTML,
                x = tspan.getBoundingClientRect().left - node.node.getBoundingClientRect().left,  //How do I get the correct x value?
                y = tspan.getBoundingClientRect().top - node.node.getBoundingClientRect().top;  //How do I get the correcy y value?

            var path = paper.print(x, y, tspanText, font, fontSize),                
                attrs = node.attrs;
            delete attrs.x;
            delete attrs.y;
            path.attr(attrs);
            path.attr('fill', '#ff0000');  //Red, for testing purposes.
        }
```

**Complete Code** [View the JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7RurJ/4/)

```
//Register Cufon Font
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('paper'), '600', '600');

var text1 = paper.text(100, 100, 'abc').attr({fill: 'none',stroke: '#000000',"stroke-width": '12',"stroke-miterlimit": '1',"font-family" : "Lobster", "font-size": '30px','stroke-opacity': '1'});
var text2 = paper.text(100, 100, 'abc').attr({fill: 'none',stroke: '#ffffff',"stroke-width": '8',"stroke-miterlimit": '1',"font-family" : "Lobster", "font-size": '30px','stroke-opacity': '1'});
var text3 = paper.text(100, 100, 'abc').attr({fill: '#000000',stroke: '#ffffff',"stroke-width": '0',"stroke-miterlimit": '1',"font-family" : "Lobster", "font-size": '30px','stroke-opacity': '1'});
var text = paper.set(text1, text2, text3);
text.attr('textFormat', 'stagger');

/* paper.textToPaths
 * Description: Converts all text nodes to paths within a paper.
 *
 * Example: paper.textToPaths();
 */
(function(R) {
    R.fn.textToPaths = function() {
        var paper   = this;

        //Loop all nodes in the paper.
        for (var node = paper.bottom; node != null; node = node.next ) {
            if ( node.node.style.display === 'none' || node.type !== "text" || node.attrs.opacity == "0") continue; //skip non-text and hidden nodes.

            //Get the font config for this text node.
            var text = node.attr('text'),
                fontFamily = node.attr('font-family'),
                fontSize = parseInt(node.attr('font-size')),
                fontWeight = node.attr('font-weight'),
                font = paper.getFont(fontFamily, fontWeight);

            //Loop through each tspan and print the path for each.
            var i,
                children = node.node.childNodes,
                len = children.length;

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var tspan = children[i],
                    tspanText = tspan.innerHTML,
                    x = tspan.getBoundingClientRect().left - node.node.getBoundingClientRect().left,  //How do I get the correct x value?
                    y = tspan.getBoundingClientRect().top - node.node.getBoundingClientRect().top;  //How do I get the correcy y value?

                var path = paper.print(x, y, tspanText, font, fontSize),                
                    attrs = node.attrs;
                delete attrs.x;
                delete attrs.y;
                path.attr(attrs);
                path.attr('fill', '#ff0000');  //Red, for testing purposes.
            }

        }

    };
})(window.Raphael);

textToPaths = function() {
    //Run textToPaths
    paper.textToPaths();
};


/* Custom Element Attribute: textFormat 
 * Description: Formats a text element to either staggered or normal text.
 *
 * Example: element.attr('textFormat, 'stagger');
 */
paper.customAttributes.textFormat = function( value ) {
    // Sets the SVG dy attribute, which Raphael doesn't control
    var selector = Raphael.svg ? 'tspan' : 'v:textpath',
        has = "hasOwnProperty",
        $node = $(this.node),
        text = $node.text(),
        $tspans = $node.find(selector);

    console.log('format');

    switch(value)
    {
        case 'stagger' :
            var stagger = function(el) {
                var R = Raphael,
                    letters = '',
                    newline = '\n';

                for (var c=0; c < text.length; c++) {
                    var letter = text[c],
                        append = '';

                    if(c < text.length - 1)
                        append = newline;
                        letters += letter+append;
                    }
                    el.attr('text', letters);
                    var children = el.node.childNodes;

                    var i,
                        a = el.attrs,
                        node = el.node,
                        len = children.length,
                        letterOffset = 0,
                        tspan,
                        tspanHeight,
                        tspanWidth,
                        tspanX,
                        prevTspan,
                        prevTspanRight = 0,
                        tspanDiff = 0,
                        tspanTemp,
                        fontSize,
                        leading = 1.2,
                        tempText;
                    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        tspan = children[i];
                        tspanHeight = tspan.getComputedTextLength();
                        tspanWidth = tspan.getComputedTextLength();
                        tspanX = tspan.getAttribute('x'),
                        prevTspanRight = tspan.getBoundingClientRect().right

                        if(tspanX !== null)
                        {
                            tspanDiff = tspanDiff + prevTspanRight - tspan.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                            var setX = parseInt(tspanX) + parseInt(tspanDiff);
                            tspan.setAttribute('x', setX);
                            tspan.setAttribute('dy', 15);
                        }
                        prevTspan = tspan;
                    }
                }
                stagger(this);
                break;
            case 'normal' :
                this.attr('text', text);
                break;
            default :
                this.attr('text', text);
                break;
        }

        eve("raphael.attr.textFormat." + this.id, this, value);

        // change no default Raphael attributes
        return {};
    };

staggerText = function() {
    //Run textToPaths
    text.attr('textFormat', 'stagger');
};
```

If anyone can help me solve this problem I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not use embedded webfonts instead?

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate the need for the font to be installed later.  You cannot embed font information within a SVG, hence why I need to convert the text glyphs to paths ;)

Comment: Sure you can, webfonts can be embedded as data URIs. Here's an example: http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/fonts/webfont-datauri.svg

Comment: That's using an embedded font-face which is fine, but the server side tools such as ImageMagick do not support font-face in SVGs, which leads back to the same problem.  I'm opting to eliminate the requirement for rendering fonts, period.  I want to ensure it looks 100% the same, without depending on varying font rendering engines.  The only way I can guarantee that is to use absolute paths.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can convert fonts to SVG/Canvas path commands using [Opentype.js](https://opentype.js.org).

The lib will return to you a series of path drawing commands; these are intended for drawing on an HTML5 `<canvas>` element.

However it is trivial to build an SVG path with those commands since the font-conversion does not include any commands that are compatible with Canvas path drawing that would be incompatible with an SVG path command.

Comment: Nice library, I wish I had of known about this 10 months ago :D

Comment: I had the exact same problem/question as Axel and I implemented Opentype.js in my SVG editor also. It works like a charm.

One problem: I have a input field which changes the text on every keyup. But i don't want to load the font on every change.. isn't there a way i can "store" the font somewhere and just recalc the path on every text change? Any ideas?

Comment: Compare the inputs to `opentype.js` and make sure you send to it only the changed characters. Then repaint the changed char yourself at the appropriate position(which you will calculate yourself). It's rather complicated to do so but necessary if you want this to be speedy. Otherwise just play with your UI. Allow the user to type characters and only on finalization do the conversion behind the scenes and 'silently' replace the fonts with the bezier representation.